# WSO2 Governance Registry: Changing Governance Store Asset Display

Tags: wso2

I would like to display more information of an asset in the Governance Registry Store portal; for e.g. displaying IP address of a server

How do I change or control the type of asset information to be displayed in the Governance Registry Store Portal?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer ["Writing extension to replicate more artifact metadata in Store"](http://asadistechspace.blogspot.com/2016/04/wso2greg-520-writing-extension-to.html#.Wehk0nWCzCK) and ["How to extend an asset's store view in WSO2 GREG 5.3.0"](https://brokensplinter.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-extend-assets-store-view-in-wso2.html) blog posts on the same requirement.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links.